# cuda with optimus just to access gpgpu

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-12.04

I have a Dell XPS L502 with the Nvidia 525M graphics card. I am only interested in using the gpgpu capabilities of the card for now.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 as a dual boot with the Windows 7 that came with the machine and followed several installation procedures for installing the CUDA driver and developer kit from Nvidia ( many re-installs of Ubuntu ). In all cases the display drops to 640x480 resolution. Best I can determine this has something to do with Optimus technology and Linux. I tried Bumblebee to no avail.

I really don't care about using the NVidia card to drive the display. Is there any way that I can just install the NVidia drivers so that a program can use the CUDA capabilities of the graphics card and I still get the full resolution on the display?

Comment: i got it =) http://cudageek.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/cuda-on-my-dell/ But now this is easier with Bumblebee 3.0. Your problem is that you have configured your X. Bumblebeed is actually like another server that get you nvidia gpu access.

Comment: +1 for Ubuntu on optimus laptop

Comment: I still use 11.10 "Oneiric" at the moment for CUDA over Optimus, with Ironhide (which doesn't seem to work correctly on 12.04) instead of Bumblebee. Would that be an option for you? (It's of course not a very good one.)

Comment: Take a look at something called `ironhide`. It's apparently a continuation of bumblebee on Ubuntu. https://github.com/MrMEEE/ironhide

Comment: Thanks. I tried marina's solution and I thinK I have the minimum I want. I can't run the graphics from Nvidia ( "[VRL}..cannot open display 8") and the fixes/work-arounds I found didn't fix or work around. I think I can use the gpu as a compute device, though. I'm having a bit of trouble linking against libcublas - can't seem to find dgemm_. I hope it is something stupid I did. If that doesn't work, I guess it will be drop back to 11.10 and use Ironhide.

Comment: Didn't want you folks to think I abandoned this thread. I tried everything I could find on the web. Re-installed 12.04, 11.10 about a dozen times and just gave up and backed all the way out to 11.04. Followed the bouncing ball of anyone of a number of sites and it works. I'll call it quits. Thanks for your help and suggestions...They kept me going.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my Alienware M11xR2, and posted the solution on the NVIDIA Forums. Unfortunately the forums are down at the moment but essentially the process is as follows:

1. Install the Nvidia Drivers, but when prompted to modify your X11 Config, select 'No'. This is because the Nvidia card cannot be used as a display device.
2. Install the CUDA SDK and **run one of the samples as root**. I found this to be a necessary step. After this you should be able to execute further CUDA programs as a normal user.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

With the new release of CUDA 5 the, comes the installation guide, there you have just one file that installs drivers, toolkit and sdk (even nvidia nsight). And one thing that got my attention is that you also have **optimus** options in the installation process.

I also have and Alienware M14x, and i understand your problem, but i also wanted the drivers to work for me, so i didn't try too hard on that.

Maybe you could give that a try and comment with the rest of us.

Here you can look for the CUDA 5 release candidate: [CUDA 5](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rc/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Guide_For_Linux.pdf)

and here is the installation guide (maybe give this a read first): [CUDA 5 Starting Guide for Linux.](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rc/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Guide_For_Linux.pdf)

Comment: Great. Thanks. Actually my cuda setup got corrupted a couple of weeks ago with an upgrade I applied. I'll check it out over the weekend.

Comment: Finally got around to loading it up. After a false start (forgot gdm is now lightdm) the package installed and seems to be running perfectly. I ran a couple of the tests and one of my own codes and all seems fine. I did have to recompile my own code as it was looking for the cuda-4 .so's

Comment: One more thing. In my case, I do have to run the little boot time script to load the drivers. No big deal and after a couple of reboots, I haven't seen a problem.

Comment: Great, so the optimus parameters really helped you! now you can test your cuda codes in linux.