# CUDA Shared Memory Access Violation

Tags: cuda

I m trying to solve TSP using parallel genetic algorithm in CUDA

i m using

```
THREAD_SIZE as 32

BLOCK_SIZE as 16
```

The shared memory i use in each block is this

```
__shared__ int population[THREAD_SIZE][NUM_OF_CITIES];
```

When the NUM_OF_CITIES is 14 or 29 the program works just fine
but when i increase the NUM_OF_CITIES to 51 , there occurs a memory access violation somewhere

and the display driver crashes..

Is it because i m using more shared memory than the limit ?
Is there a way to go around this ?

**[EDITED]**
As *Robert Crovella* pointed out the problem seems to me the time taken for the exectuion of each thread

inside each thread I perform the following operations

> for(int k = 0 ; k < 100 ; k++ )    {
>      //Selection
>      //CrossOver
>      //Evolution (Using the Two Opt heuristics)
>   }

in the loop if i remove the **Two Opt evolution** step  *ie.* the most expensive step in the loop, the kernel works just fine ...

Is ther any way to make the kernel execute for more than 2 seconds ?
Would buying a better and powerful card solve this ?

I m using **GTS 450** , planning to buy **GTX 650 Ti** in the near future
Would this solve the problem ?

Comment: Are you running on windows? If so a display driver crash may be occurring when your kernel takes more than about 2 seconds to execute due to windows TDR mechanism.  There might be nothing wrong with your code except that it is taking too long (does it take longer when you increase NUM_OF_CITIES?).  Otherwise how are you assessing that "there is a memory access violation somewhere"?  It doesn't appear to me that you are using more than 16KB of shared memory per block, which should be OK.  It might help to show your actual kernel invocation as well as your computation of the launch parameters.

Comment: If you suspect you have an access violation, could you please also post the kernel instructions, and particularly those in which you manipulate the shared memory?

Comment: @RobertCrovella : the problem seems to be what you told , how to solve it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: try searching "cuda windows TDR" in the search box on the upper right corner of this page.  The first returned result should give you some ideas.  Specifically the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177214/disabling-tdr-for-cuda-in-windows-8).

Comment: be advised of course that if you modify TDR settings you do so at your own risk.  I'm not recommending it.  It's there for a reason, and at a minimum you run the risk of hanging your machine with an errant kernel if you disable TDR.

Comment: @RobertCrovella instead of looping 100 times inside the kernel can i loop the entire kernel invocation in the host 100 times ? will this solve the problem ?

Comment: It may solve the problem.  The critical factor is the duration of the kernel execution, not how many times you run the kernel.  If you get the duration of the kernel execution down below 2s I believe it should not trip a TDR event.  This is not really my area of expertise however.

Comment: @RobertCrovella : for the above same problem .. will the number blocks increase the execution time ? asking this because there is no part of code in kernel that is dependent on the size of the blocks , Yet if increase the block size to 128 , i get the same above error .. Display driver crashes

Comment: Yes, generally speaking, if I increase the number of blocks, I am creating more work for the machine, and so the machine takes longer.  Perhaps you might look at some [introductory webinar courses](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars).  The driver crash could be evidence of a hung kernel as well, e.g. an infinite loop.  You haven't posted your kernel code so most of my answers here are speculation.  It's also not possible to continue this discussion endlessly in the comments.